# Proving a case of Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently looking for some confirmation on a rather simple proof. I introduced the question and my proof. Thank you for your time.

Let ${v_1,v_2,…,v_k}$ be vectors of a vector space V. Prove that, if one of the vi's is the vector zero, then the system ${v_1,v_2,…,v_k}$ is linearly dependent.

My proof:

0 = ${\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha _2v_2    +,…,+ \alpha _iv_i, .. .+v_k}$

For a collection of vectors to be linearly independent the system of the equations can be zero is if all the scalars ${\alpha _1, \alpha _2 ... , \alpha _k } $ are equal to zero. In this case however, if ${v_i}$ is the zero vector then $\alpha _i$ can take any value and this will still equal zero.

Therefore, this fails to comply with linear independence making it linearly dependent.

Comment: That is the right idea.  Best to be explicit: set $\alpha_i = 1$ and $\alpha_j = 0$ for all other $j$.

Comment: You have a typo in this. Your discussion says "for something to be linearly dependent" when it should say "for a collection of vectors to be linearly independent" ...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, exactly. Just like you've said, you get a nontrivial linear combination to the identity by simply making the scalar attached to the zero vector nonzero. I might even be explicit, and produce any such linear combination, the most fundamental of which being $$ v_j = \begin{cases}1 & j = i \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: Thank you, I know this may seem rather trivial, but I feel as though confirmation is a must!

Comment: I get it. You want to make sure you're on the right track before you get the wrong idea. It's totally normal.